# Scope of variable with out parameter

Tags: c#, scope, local-variables

**Example:**

I have the following code block:

```
if (!int.TryParse("123", out var parsedNumber))
{
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(parsedNumber);
```

The output in console is: 123

**Question:**

How is it possible, that the line `Console.WriteLine(parsedNumber);` knows about `parsedNumber`?

According to my understanding, `parsedNumber` should only available in the `if-block`, shouldn't it?

If I try this:

```
foreach (var data in dataList)
{
   data += "something";
}

Console.WriteLine(data);
```

`Console.WriteLine(data);` can't find `data`.

---

I think, that the solution is the out parameter, but I'm not sure. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, as you suspect the difference is that "out" modifier.

It is a feature added in C# 7 that allows you to declare the variable at the point where you want to use it as an argument.

That might be convenient as otherwise you'd have to declare `parsedNumber` before the method call.

You can read more about it here, under "Out variables".

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

**EDIT**

As for why the variable is still in scope outside of the if, that can certainly be confusing, but it was a design choice when implementing this, specifically for the "if" case and precisely so that it could be used in "try" methods.

You can refer to this comment (actually you can take a look at the whole discussion to see the different points of view there were on how to implement this).

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12939#issuecomment-255650834

Comment: I think what he/she asks is that why out of if(){}, we can still access to parsedNumber

Comment: @CodeContributor: yeah, that makes sense as well, added an EDIT to my answer to cover that

Comment: Is there a way to make it less visible (e.g. private)?

Comment: @AhmedSuror No, and this is about scope, not access, so `private` makes no sense here.

Comment: To me, "explain this" means explain how it works, not just the motive behind the decision.  This is further implied by the question title.  If the scope of the `out`-declared variable isn't the body of the if block, what _is_ the scope?

Answer (score 0):

**Prior to C# 7.0**

The `out` keyword was used to pass a method argument's reference. Before a variable is passed as an out argument, it must be declared.

```
var parsedNumber;
if (!int.TryParse("123", out parsedNumber))
{
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(parsedNumber);
```

**In C# 7.0**

You can define a method's `out` parameters directly in the method. The new code looks like

```
if (!int.TryParse("123", out var parsedNumber))
{
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(parsedNumber);
```

Reference:
[Whats-new-in-csharp-7-0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

Comment: All you have done is to repeat what the asker already knows.  You haven't provided any explanation.

Comment: Additionally, is `out var parsedNumber` in the pre-7.0 code a typo?